# Выронять слова в одну колонку в HTML

Tags: html, css

Доброго времени суток,я делаю одно веб приложение,но появилась проблема с оформлением.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть идеи как сделать так,чтобы слова выстроились в ровную колонку?

мой HTML-код:

```
<body>
    <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row" ng-repeat="band in bands"  ng-class="$even ? 'odd' : 'even'">
                <img ng-src="{{band.image}}"> 
                <div style="display:inline-block;position:relative;bottom:50px;margin-left:100px" class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>{{band.artist}}</p>
                </div>
                <div  style="display:inline-block; position:relative;bottom:50px;margin-left:100px" class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>{{band.track}}</p>
                </div>
                <div  style="display:inline-block;position:relative;bottom:50px;margin-left:100px" class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>{{band.collection}}</p>
                </div>
                <div  style="display:inline-block;position:relative;bottom:50px; margin-left:100px" class="col-sm-4">
                    <p>{{band.genre}}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Попробуйте задать в стилях свойство width для каждого блока

Comment: А параграфы сделать одной ширины задать `text-align:center;` нет возможности?

Comment: ну как минимум на глаз вы заюзали 16 столбцов из 12. идентичные стили вынесли бы в css, читать эту кашу неудобго

Comment: @Air сделал,получилось,спасибо

Comment: Всегда пожалуйста...